# query to convert a union all query to a single query when conditional cross join is used

Tags: join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created below 2 tables for example :

```
create table #fruit(id int, fname varchar(20));
create table #fruitinfo (dayid int, id int);
```

I inserted below mentioned values :

```
INSERT INTO #fruit values (1, 'apple');
INSERT INTO #fruit values (2, 'banana');
INSERT INTO #fruit values (3, 'grapes');
INSERT INTO #fruit values (4, 'all');

insert into #fruitinfo values (1, 1);
insert into #fruitinfo values (2, 1);
insert into #fruitinfo values (2, 2);
insert into #fruitinfo values (3, 3);
insert into #fruitinfo values (4, 4);
```

For all the days where the id is either in (1,2,3), i have to display specific fruit name.  For all the records where id is 4 i.e. 'ALL', i have to show 3 records showing each fruit.  I've written below union query for the same.  Just wanted to check if we have any way in which this could be accomplished within a single query without using union/union all?

```
select fi.dayid 
       , f.fname
from #fruitinfo fi
inner join #fruit f
  on fi.id = f.id
where f.id in (1,2,3)  
UNION ALL
select fi.dayid 
       , f.fname
from #fruitinfo fi
cross join #fruit f
where f.id in (1,2,3)  
and fi.id = 4;
```

The results are as under :

```
dayid   fname
1       apple
2       apple
2       banana
3       grapes
4       apple
4       banana
4       grapes
```

Comment: I don't think you can avoid `UNION ALL` operator here. What's the problem with `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Nothing, just wanted to check for other options as one of my colleagues told me that there could be a way in which this can be done in a single query and not a union one